# Django queryset filtering

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 2 main entities in my models.py:

```
class IPGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

These two tables are linked through a 3rd through table as follows:

```
class IPGroupToTag(models.Model):
    ip_group = models.ForeignKey(IPGroup)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

My requirement is to find all the **tags** with the **name** "SecurityZone" when the only input I have is the **name** of the **IPGroup**. My attempt is as follows:

```
ip_group_id = IPGroup.objects.get(name="test_ip_group").id
zone = IPGroupToTag.objects.filter(ip_group_id=ip_group_id).values('tag__name')
```

which gives me the following Queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'tag__name': 'Title'}, {'tag__name': 'Site'}, {'tag__name': 'SecurityZone'}, {'tag__name': 'DataCenter'}, {'tag__name': 'Pod'}]>
```

How do I then find the id of the tag with the name **SecurityZone** and then find its **value**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IPGroupToTag.objects.filter(ip_group__name='test_ip_group',tag__name='SecurityZone').values('tag__value')
```

this one query will do what you are trying to find

Comment: This works really well...one final thing..the final output of is of the type Queryset as follows:<QuerySet [{'tag__value': 'core'}]>. How can i get just the value core ?

Comment: Exprator..i did this..IPGroupToTag.objects.filter(ip_group__name=request["source_ip_group"], tag__name='SecurityZone').values('tag__value')[0]['tag__value']....not sure if this is the best way to do this..

Comment: use a for loop save the query to a variable and then do `for i in variable: print(i['tag_value']`